# How To Insert LZMA Files

Tags: android, kernel

I hope someone can help me on this. This is for the Freescale IMX6Q tablet (Zenithink C-94). This really is a good tablet that never a chance. Originally came out with ICS 4.0 on it. Freescale released the source for Jelly Bean 4.3. I have built a rom from that source (and a AOSPA+ rom) , but the problem is with Zenithink. There are the proprietary blobs patched to the "boot.img" and "uImage_update". I need these blobs to get the tablet to initialize, but Zenithink hides behind a wall of silence. I have requested the source for the u-boot and boot.img, but have gotten squat. I have tried to pressure them by reporting a GPL violation here: license-violation@gnu.org and so far nothing. I have been left with reverse engineering this.

The "uImage_update" is essentially a uImage by what I can tell. On this tablet this writes to partition mmcblk08; basically a pre-file system that is up and running at initialization. The kicker is this is what I pulled off that:

```
Linux rev 1.0 ext4 filesystem data, UUID=80720123-59a2-fc56-b69d-aaf1e69ad9ae, volume name "vender" (extents) (large files)
```

This is a dev/zero section on that partition; meaning it overwrites the data from the first initramfs with zeros. Try to go into an adb shell:

```
# cat /dev/zero
```

and you'll see what I mean; you get nothing shown. I have extracted the initramfs from this uImage_update and this is what it looks like:

[initramfs_uImage.zip](http://www.mediafire.com/download/6e30ctaz6ydn58t/initramfs_uImage.zip)

This is very different from what I have seen. Check in the "res", "sbin", and "system" folders (also the "mkext2.sh). I then extracted and decompressed the .gzip data file out of the uImage_update and named it "update". I then typed:

```
$ binwalk update > update.walk
```

to get this:

```
DECIMAL     HEX         DESCRIPTION
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
185916      0x2D63C     ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "system" 
186036      0x2D6B4     ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "system/lib" 
186160      0x2D730     ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "system/lib/libc.so" 
468472      0x725F8     ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "system/lib/libext2_e2p.so" 
487080      0x76EA8     ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "system/lib/libusbhost.so" 
496836      0x794C4     ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "system/lib/libcutils.so" 
560808      0x88EA8     ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "system/lib/libext2_uuid.so" 
570612      0x8B4F4     ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "system/lib/libext4_utils.so" 
622588      0x97FFC     ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "system/lib/liblog.so" 
636540      0x9B67C     ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "system/lib/libstdc++.so" 
642124      0x9CC4C     ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "system/lib/libz.so" 
738176      0xB4380     ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "system/lib/libext2fs.so" 
843628      0xCDF6C     ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "system/lib/libext2_blkid.so" 
872304      0xD4F70     ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "system/lib/libext2_com_err.so" 
882096      0xD75B0     ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "system/lib/libm.so" 
969572      0xECB64     ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "system/lib/libext2_profile.so" 
983680      0xF0280     ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "system/bin" 
983804      0xF02FC     ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "system/bin/toolbox" 
1091336     0x10A708    ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "system/bin/ext4fixup" 
1097032     0x10BD48    ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "system/bin/setup_fs" 
1102812     0x10D3DC    ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "system/bin/newfs_msdos" 
1210348     0x1277EC    ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "system/bin/linker" 
1250068     0x131314    ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "system/bin/sh" 
1402156     0x15652C    ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "system/bin/ext2simg" 
1412060     0x158BDC    ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "system/bin/mke2fs" 
1447104     0x1614C0    ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "system/bin/mkdosfs" 
1554636     0x17B8CC    ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "system/bin/make_ext4fs" 
1560344     0x17CF18    ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "system/bin/logcat" 
1574488     0x180658    ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "sbin" 
1574604     0x1806CC    ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "sbin/test.sh" 
1577204     0x1810F4    ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "sbin/product_tool.sh_1" 
1579444     0x1819B4    ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "sbin/product_tool.sh_2" 
1581776     0x1822D0    ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "sbin/ueventd" 
1680556     0x19A4AC    ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "sbin/product_tool.sh2" 
1684784     0x19B530    ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "sbin/product_tool.sh" 
1689836     0x19C8EC    ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "sbin/ts_calibrator" 
1748816     0x1AAF50    ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "sbin/busybox" 
3383044     0x339F04    ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "sbin/sh" 
3535128     0x35F118    ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "sbin/product_tool.sh_5" 
3540032     0x360440    ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "sbin/recovery" 
3818032     0x3A4230    ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "sbin/product_tool.sh3" 
3821452     0x3A4F8C    ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "sbin/adbd" 
3964160     0x3C7D00    ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "sbin/product_tool.sh_v0.1" 
3968736     0x3C8EE0    ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "sbin/mkext2.sh" 
3971392     0x3C9940    ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "sbin/product_tool.sh_v0.2" 
3974620     0x3CA5DC    ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "ueventd.freescale.rc" 
3977084     0x3CAF7C    ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "sys" 
3977200     0x3CAFF0    ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "tmp" 
3977316     0x3CB064    ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "ueventd.goldfish.rc" 
3977720     0x3CB1F8    ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "res" 
3977836     0x3CB26C    ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "res/images" 
3977960     0x3CB2E8    ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "res/images/icon_installing.png" 
4003368     0x3D1628    ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "res/images/indeterminate01.png" 
4004188     0x3D195C    ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "res/images/progress_fill.png" 
4004732     0x3D1B7C    ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "res/images/indeterminate03.png" 
4005540     0x3D1EA4    ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "res/images/icon_installing_overlay07.png" 
4015756     0x3D468C    ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "res/images/icon_installing_overlay02.png" 
4025900     0x3D6E2C    ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "res/images/indeterminate04.png" 
4026712     0x3D7158    ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "res/images/icon_error.png" 
4046156     0x3DBD4C    ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "res/images/icon_installing_overlay04.png" 
4056128     0x3DE440    ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "res/images/icon_installing_overlay05.png" 
4066144     0x3E0B60    ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "res/images/indeterminate05.png" 
4066972     0x3E0E9C    ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "res/images/icon_installing_overlay03.png" 
4076908     0x3E356C    ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "res/images/indeterminate02.png" 
4077740     0x3E38AC    ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "res/images/icon_installing_overlay06.png" 
4087836     0x3E601C    ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "res/images/progress_empty.png" 
4088096     0x3E6120    ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "res/images/indeterminate06.png" 
4088916     0x3E6454    ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "res/images/icon_installing_overlay01.png" 
4099164     0x3E8C5C    ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "res/keys" 
4100692     0x3E9254    ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "ueventd.rc" 
4104644     0x3EA1C4    ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "data" 
4104760     0x3EA238    ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "init" 
4203532     0x40240C    ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "init.rc" 
4205208     0x402A98    ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "proc" 
4205324     0x402B0C    ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "default.prop" 
4206964     0x403174    ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "etc" 
4207080     0x4031E8    ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "etc/recovery.fstab" 
4207564     0x4033CC    ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "dev" 
4207680     0x403440    ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "mkext2.sh" 
4210328     0x403E98    ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "TRAILER!!!" 
10454976    0x9F87C0    Linux kernel version "3.0.35 (android@amdroid) (gcc version 4.4.3 (GCC) ) #258 SMP PRersion 4.4.3 (GCC) ) #258 SMP PREEMPT Mon Nov 19 18:58:49 CST 2REEMPT Mon Nov 19 18:58:49 CST 20122012"
10468824    0x9FBDD8    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x02, dictionary size: 16777216 bytes, uncompressed size: 50331648 bytes
10470224    0x9FC350    gzip compressed data, from Unix, NULL date: Wed Dec 31 17:00:00 1969, max compression
10489368    0xA00E18    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x01, dictionary size: 33554432 bytes, uncompressed size: 50331648 bytes
10546214    0xA0EC26    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x02, dictionary size: 33554432 bytes, uncompressed size: 133128 bytes
10596880    0xA1B210    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x48, dictionary size: 33554432 bytes, uncompressed size: 50331648 bytes
10597168    0xA1B330    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x03, dictionary size: 16777216 bytes, uncompressed size: 67108864 bytes
10615161    0xA1F979    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x75, dictionary size: 1048576 bytes, uncompressed size: 262144 bytes
10615197    0xA1F99D    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x6E, dictionary size: 1048576 bytes, uncompressed size: 262144 bytes
10615233    0xA1F9C1    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x64, dictionary size: 1048576 bytes, uncompressed size: 262144 bytes
10625784    0xA222F8    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x01, dictionary size: 33554432 bytes, uncompressed size: 167772160 bytes
10678417    0xA2F091    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x02, dictionary size: 1048576 bytes, uncompressed size: 50593792 bytes
10698516    0xA33F14    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x01, dictionary size: 16777216 bytes, uncompressed size: 92372993 bytes
10698732    0xA33FEC    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x01, dictionary size: 16777216 bytes, uncompressed size: 25231361 bytes
10698828    0xA3404C    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x01, dictionary size: 16777216 bytes, uncompressed size: 16842753 bytes
10698900    0xA34094    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x02, dictionary size: 16777216 bytes, uncompressed size: 25296897 bytes
10699044    0xA34124    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x01, dictionary size: 16777216 bytes, uncompressed size: 151060737 bytes
10699116    0xA3416C    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x02, dictionary size: 16777216 bytes, uncompressed size: 92340481 bytes
10699188    0xA341B4    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x01, dictionary size: 16777216 bytes, uncompressed size: 151060737 bytes
10699260    0xA341FC    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x02, dictionary size: 16777216 bytes, uncompressed size: 92340481 bytes
10706088    0xA35CA8    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x0A, dictionary size: 33554432 bytes, uncompressed size: 33554434 bytes
10713427    0xA37953    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0xC0, dictionary size: 65536 bytes, uncompressed size: 1 bytes
10735476    0xA3CF74    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x02, dictionary size: 33554432 bytes, uncompressed size: 234881024 bytes
11474468    0xAF1624    ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "oop (skipped) already calibrated this CPU" 
12398841    0xBD30F9    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x04, dictionary size: 65536 bytes, uncompressed size: 98304000 bytes
12430328    0xBDABF8    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x01, dictionary size: 33554432 bytes, uncompressed size: 4 bytes
12430373    0xBDAC25    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x02, dictionary size: 65536 bytes, uncompressed size: 1179648 bytes
12460472    0xBE21B8    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x01, dictionary size: 33554432 bytes, uncompressed size: 50331648 bytes
12466532    0xBE3964    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x02, dictionary size: 16777216 bytes, uncompressed size: 33554432 bytes
12473624    0xBE5518    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x01, dictionary size: 33554432 bytes, uncompressed size: 50331648 bytes
12474072    0xBE56D8    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x01, dictionary size: 33554432 bytes, uncompressed size: 50331648 bytes
12513680    0xBEF190    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x01, dictionary size: 33554432 bytes, uncompressed size: 1 bytes
12544155    0xBF689B    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x01, dictionary size: 65536 bytes, uncompressed size: 2057732 bytes
12544175    0xBF68AF    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x01, dictionary size: 65536 bytes, uncompressed size: 2049025 bytes
12544195    0xBF68C3    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x01, dictionary size: 65536 bytes, uncompressed size: 2050048 bytes
12544215    0xBF68D7    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x01, dictionary size: 65536 bytes, uncompressed size: 2032640 bytes
12544235    0xBF68EB    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x01, dictionary size: 65536 bytes, uncompressed size: 2049281 bytes
12544255    0xBF68FF    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x01, dictionary size: 65536 bytes, uncompressed size: 2049537 bytes
12544275    0xBF6913    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x01, dictionary size: 65536 bytes, uncompressed size: 2049792 bytes
12544295    0xBF6927    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x01, dictionary size: 65536 bytes, uncompressed size: 1847574 bytes
12544315    0xBF693B    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x01, dictionary size: 65536 bytes, uncompressed size: 1843222 bytes
12544435    0xBF69B3    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x01, dictionary size: 65536 bytes, uncompressed size: 12722196 bytes
12544475    0xBF69DB    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x01, dictionary size: 65536 bytes, uncompressed size: 12722198 bytes
12544695    0xBF6AB7    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x01, dictionary size: 65536 bytes, uncompressed size: 66070 bytes
12544895    0xBF6B7F    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x01, dictionary size: 65536 bytes, uncompressed size: 15679511 bytes
12544915    0xBF6B93    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x01, dictionary size: 65536 bytes, uncompressed size: 12526989 bytes
12544935    0xBF6BA7    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x01, dictionary size: 65536 bytes, uncompressed size: 12526990 bytes
12544955    0xBF6BBB    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x01, dictionary size: 65536 bytes, uncompressed size: 12526913 bytes
12544975    0xBF6BCF    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x01, dictionary size: 65536 bytes, uncompressed size: 12526922 bytes
12544995    0xBF6BE3    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x01, dictionary size: 65536 bytes, uncompressed size: 12526849 bytes
12545015    0xBF6BF7    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x01, dictionary size: 65536 bytes, uncompressed size: 12526850 bytes
12545035    0xBF6C0B    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x01, dictionary size: 65536 bytes, uncompressed size: 12526851 bytes
12545055    0xBF6C1F    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x01, dictionary size: 65536 bytes, uncompressed size: 12526852 bytes
12545075    0xBF6C33    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x01, dictionary size: 65536 bytes, uncompressed size: 2105360 bytes
12545535    0xBF6DFF    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x01, dictionary size: 65536 bytes, uncompressed size: 2126102 bytes
12545555    0xBF6E13    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x01, dictionary size: 65536 bytes, uncompressed size: 2126614 bytes
12545575    0xBF6E27    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x01, dictionary size: 65536 bytes, uncompressed size: 2122518 bytes
12545595    0xBF6E3B    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x01, dictionary size: 65536 bytes, uncompressed size: 2126103 bytes
12545635    0xBF6E63    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x01, dictionary size: 65536 bytes, uncompressed size: 15675410 bytes
12545655    0xBF6E77    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x01, dictionary size: 65536 bytes, uncompressed size: 15675411 bytes
12545675    0xBF6E8B    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x01, dictionary size: 65536 bytes, uncompressed size: 15675412 bytes
12545695    0xBF6E9F    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x01, dictionary size: 65536 bytes, uncompressed size: 15675413 bytes
12545715    0xBF6EB3    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x01, dictionary size: 65536 bytes, uncompressed size: 15675414 bytes
12545735    0xBF6EC7    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x01, dictionary size: 65536 bytes, uncompressed size: 15679510 bytes
12545755    0xBF6EDB    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x01, dictionary size: 65536 bytes, uncompressed size: 15675415 bytes
12545775    0xBF6EEF    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x01, dictionary size: 65536 bytes, uncompressed size: 15679511 bytes
12554493    0xBF90FD    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x02, dictionary size: 1048576 bytes, uncompressed size: 1073741824 bytes
12554517    0xBF9115    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x02, dictionary size: 1048576 bytes, uncompressed size: 1073741824 bytes
12554589    0xBF915D    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x02, dictionary size: 2097152 bytes, uncompressed size: 1073741824 bytes
12554613    0xBF9175    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x02, dictionary size: 2097152 bytes, uncompressed size: 1073741824 bytes
12554685    0xBF91BD    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x02, dictionary size: 4194304 bytes, uncompressed size: 1073741824 bytes
12554709    0xBF91D5    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x02, dictionary size: 4194304 bytes, uncompressed size: 1073741824 bytes
12554781    0xBF921D    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x02, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 1073741824 bytes
12554805    0xBF9235    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x02, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 1073741824 bytes
12554829    0xBF924D    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x02, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 1073741824 bytes
12554949    0xBF92C5    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x02, dictionary size: 16777216 bytes, uncompressed size: 1073741824 bytes
12560849    0xBFA9D1    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x13, dictionary size: 65536 bytes, uncompressed size: 7340032 bytes
12568984    0xBFC998    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x01, dictionary size: 131072 bytes, uncompressed size: 2 bytes
12569104    0xBFCA10    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x09, dictionary size: 131072 bytes, uncompressed size: 2 bytes
12569124    0xBFCA24    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x0A, dictionary size: 131072 bytes, uncompressed size: 2 bytes
12573615    0xBFDBAF    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x01, dictionary size: 16777216 bytes, uncompressed size: 896 bytes
12573635    0xBFDBC3    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x01, dictionary size: 16777216 bytes, uncompressed size: 896 bytes
12573655    0xBFDBD7    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x01, dictionary size: 16777216 bytes, uncompressed size: 896 bytes
12573675    0xBFDBEB    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x01, dictionary size: 16777216 bytes, uncompressed size: 896 bytes
12573695    0xBFDBFF    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x01, dictionary size: 16777216 bytes, uncompressed size: 896 bytes
12573715    0xBFDC13    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x01, dictionary size: 16777216 bytes, uncompressed size: 896 bytes
12580217    0xBFF579    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x01, dictionary size: 33554432 bytes, uncompressed size: 49276 bytes
12605245    0xC0573D    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x01, dictionary size: 131072 bytes, uncompressed size: 196608 bytes
12605429    0xC057F5    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x01, dictionary size: 131072 bytes, uncompressed size: 196608 bytes
12605613    0xC058AD    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x01, dictionary size: 131072 bytes, uncompressed size: 196608 bytes
12605797    0xC05965    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x01, dictionary size: 131072 bytes, uncompressed size: 196608 bytes
12606165    0xC05AD5    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x01, dictionary size: 131072 bytes, uncompressed size: 196608 bytes
12606809    0xC05D59    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x01, dictionary size: 131072 bytes, uncompressed size: 196608 bytes
12631676    0xC0BE7C    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x01, dictionary size: 33554432 bytes, uncompressed size: 456912 bytes
12636813    0xC0D28D    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x04, dictionary size: 262144 bytes, uncompressed size: 65536 bytes
12636901    0xC0D2E5    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x04, dictionary size: 262144 bytes, uncompressed size: 65536 bytes
12636989    0xC0D33D    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x04, dictionary size: 262144 bytes, uncompressed size: 65536 bytes
12637077    0xC0D395    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x04, dictionary size: 262144 bytes, uncompressed size: 65536 bytes
12637165    0xC0D3ED    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x04, dictionary size: 262144 bytes, uncompressed size: 65536 bytes
12637253    0xC0D445    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x04, dictionary size: 262144 bytes, uncompressed size: 65536 bytes
12637341    0xC0D49D    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x04, dictionary size: 262144 bytes, uncompressed size: 65536 bytes
12637429    0xC0D4F5    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x04, dictionary size: 262144 bytes, uncompressed size: 65536 bytes
12637457    0xC0D511    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x01, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 2097152 bytes
12637501    0xC0D53D    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x01, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 2097152 bytes
12637517    0xC0D54D    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x04, dictionary size: 262144 bytes, uncompressed size: 65536 bytes
12637605    0xC0D5A5    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x04, dictionary size: 262144 bytes, uncompressed size: 65536 bytes
12637693    0xC0D5FD    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x04, dictionary size: 262144 bytes, uncompressed size: 65536 bytes
12637781    0xC0D655    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x04, dictionary size: 262144 bytes, uncompressed size: 65536 bytes
12637869    0xC0D6AD    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x04, dictionary size: 262144 bytes, uncompressed size: 65536 bytes
12637957    0xC0D705    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x04, dictionary size: 262144 bytes, uncompressed size: 65536 bytes
12638045    0xC0D75D    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x04, dictionary size: 262144 bytes, uncompressed size: 65536 bytes
12638133    0xC0D7B5    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x04, dictionary size: 262144 bytes, uncompressed size: 65536 bytes
12638221    0xC0D80D    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x04, dictionary size: 262144 bytes, uncompressed size: 65536 bytes
12638309    0xC0D865    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x04, dictionary size: 262144 bytes, uncompressed size: 65536 bytes
12638397    0xC0D8BD    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x04, dictionary size: 262144 bytes, uncompressed size: 65536 bytes
12638485    0xC0D915    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x04, dictionary size: 262144 bytes, uncompressed size: 65536 bytes
12638573    0xC0D96D    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x04, dictionary size: 262144 bytes, uncompressed size: 65536 bytes
12638661    0xC0D9C5    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x04, dictionary size: 262144 bytes, uncompressed size: 65536 bytes
12638749    0xC0DA1D    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x04, dictionary size: 262144 bytes, uncompressed size: 65536 bytes
12638837    0xC0DA75    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x04, dictionary size: 262144 bytes, uncompressed size: 65536 bytes
12638925    0xC0DACD    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x04, dictionary size: 262144 bytes, uncompressed size: 65536 bytes
12640200    0xC0DFC8    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x01, dictionary size: 16777216 bytes, uncompressed size: 654311424 bytes
12640232    0xC0DFE8    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x01, dictionary size: 16777216 bytes, uncompressed size: 654311424 bytes
12640264    0xC0E008    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x01, dictionary size: 16777216 bytes, uncompressed size: 704643072 bytes
12640296    0xC0E028    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x01, dictionary size: 16777216 bytes, uncompressed size: 704643072 bytes
12646716    0xC0F93C    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x01, dictionary size: 16777216 bytes, uncompressed size: 50331648 bytes
12661391    0xC1328F    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0xC0, dictionary size: 524288 bytes, uncompressed size: 720896 bytes
12675172    0xC16864    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x02, dictionary size: 33554432 bytes, uncompressed size: 134217728 bytes
```

This, as you can see, shows the cpio, kernel, gzip, and LZMA files. The .gzip here is the configuration file for the kernel. I did the same with the uImage I built, from the freescale ICS source. This was done so I could compare the to images to isolate the extra files from Zenithink. Then I compared the ICS source to the JB 4.3 source I built to see the changes from ISC to JB. The kernels are essentially the same. I know that threre will be a difference between the builds (ICS=GCC 4.4.3 and JB=GCC 4.6). I extracted these extra (.LZMA) files (binaries) from the original uImage_update to put into the JB uImage.

Next, was the boot.img to boot up the device. I have extracted the initramfs from that:

[initramfs_boot.zip](http://www.mediafire.com/download/5yj8mq7lw2grtlm/initramfs_boot.zip)

As one can see, this is very different form the uImage_update. I followed the process as I did with above and I extracted the extra (.LZMA) files (binaries) from the original boot.img to put into the JB boot.img. So now you have a little history traveling down this rabbit hole, My question is: How do I put these .LZMA files into the JB uImage (to be built and named "uImage_update") and JB boot.img? I know you can use the DD utility because I can extract the LZMA files using it; like this (example):

```
$ dd if=update bs=1 skip=12675172 of=last_LZMA_file
```

I just do not know how to insert new LZMA files, say at the end, or between whatever decimals. I do know it comes down to the uImage_update and boot.img to get this to work. I've tried updating the "initramfs" to match the way it is in JB, for both these images, but that did not work. Maybe there is a way to build these LZMA files into a module and load them into the kernel that way. I don't know. Anyway, I know someone here can help with this. Please help. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This question has bee posted on [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/497315/how-to-add-lzma-files) and [Android Enthusiasts](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/77170/how-to-insert-lzma-files).  As it is a question about implementation or debugging, it really isn't appropriate here either (please read the [help/on-topic] to get a better idea of the types of questions P.SE is for).  I have cast a vote to migrate this to Stack Overflow (note Android Enthusiasts [help center](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) also provides this guidance).